# How to reply to Facebook wall posts?

Tags: facebook

If someone posts on your Facebook Wall, is the standard way to reply as a comment on that wall post or as a wall post on that person's wall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way would be to reply as a comment, as this would appear below the person's post in his/her wall. If you post on his wall he will have dig in through all posts to make sense out of what you have posted.